# Multiple versions of react (react-dom uses old react dependency)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I was getting the famous [two versions loaded error](https://gist.github.com/jimfb/4faa6cbfb1ef476bd105). I ran the line `npm ls | grep react`and got the following:

```
├─┬ react@15.1.0
├── react-addons-css-transition-group@15.0.2
├─┬ react-big-calendar@0.9.12
│ ├─┬ react@15.1.0
│ ├── react-dom@15.1.0
│ ├── react-overlays@0.6.3
│ ├── react-prop-types@0.2.2
├─┬ react-datetime@2.1.0
│ └─┬ react-onclickoutside@4.9.0
├── react-dom@15.1.0
│ ├─┬ react@0.14.8
│ └── react-addons-update@0.14.8
```

It seems that react-dom uses `react@0.14.8` while the rest of my project uses `react@15.1.0`.

What do I do to make react-dom not load this older version of react? I thought that this was the most up-to-date version of react-dom.

Note: I am using npm version 2.15.1 and node version v4.4.4

Comment: When I run into such issues, I delete my `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` again. (I suspect that sometimes the transitive dependencies are not updated properly by npm.)

Answer (score 1):

You can try https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dedupe, if Nicole's comment, with clean reinstall, does not help.